# How to export addresses of a specific Exchange Distribution List

Tags: exchange, distribution-lists

I am trying to export a .csv file of names/email addresses from a specific Exchange (online) Distribution List. I see that I can export all Contacts in the Exchange Admin Center, but I can't find a way to just get a list of who is on a specific DL. Is this possible in Exchange Admin Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **But I can't find a way to just get a list of who is on a specific DL. Is this possible in Exchange Admin Center?**

Do you want to export the members of a specific DL to a CSV file which includes the members' displaynames and the DL's names/email addresses? If so, based on my knowledge, realizing this action via EAC seems not be available.

However, you could try another method(**PowerShell**), the following steps are for your reference:

1. **[Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps#connect-to-exchange-online)** via **Windows PowerShell**:[image]
2. Create a **.ps1** file and copy/paste the content of the following script in it (Specify the DL names and local path you want):

   ```
    $dls = Get-DistributionGroup | where {($_.Identity -eq "<DL1 Name>") -or ($_.Identity -eq "<DL2 Name>")}
    $member = foreach($dl in $dls) {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $dl.Name | Select-Object @{n="MemberDisplayName"; e={$_.DisplayName}}, @{n="MemberEmailAddress"; e={$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}},
    @{n="GroupName"; e={$dl.Identity}}, @{n="GroupEmailAddress"; e={$dl.PrimarySmtpAddress}} }
    $member | Select-Object MemberDisplayName, MemberEmailAddress, GroupName, GroupEmailAddress | Export-Csv <LocalPath>\Member.csv
   ```
3. Run the .ps1 file in the PowerShell，after that, a csv file will be exported in the specific local path:
   [image]

Hope the above method is helpful to you:)

Comment: I am getting an AccessDenied error when logging in. I have successfully connected to Exchange online thru PowerShell before, when I did a G Suite migration - I will have to do some more research to see exactly how I did that...

Comment: Ok I had to use a different login command, as I have 2FA turned on. When I run the above ps1 file (I had to insert a few linebreaks to get it to parse), I get the error: `where : The term '$.Identity' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` I am using EXO V2 module v1.0.1.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the *underline* character missed because of the format of the text, try to add them between "$" and "Identity".

Comment: We are getting closer! It now works... but the first 2 columns in the .csv file are blank. Where is a list of member names I can look at to choose from?

Comment: Found it - missing the underscores again in  `$.DisplayName` and `$.PrimarySmtpAddress`. Adding those did it. Can you update your code in yr answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that the method is helpful to you:)

> **Can you update your code in yr answer?**

Sorry, I still couldn't edit and add the underscores in my answer due to the text format, therefore, I provide the following snapshot for your reference:[image]

Comment: Looks like you're fairly new here - the mods frown on making a comment as an answer to a question :) I suggest deleting this "answer," and I will go ahead and modify your answer. In the future, you can use the "code block" formatting, and that will preserve all the crazy characters.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and modification, I will try that :)